# Docker multi-stage, Java simple class

Tags: java, docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I have aproblem when creating multi assembly in Docker. I get this error error invalid or corrupt jarfile

```
FROM openjdk:18-jdk-alpine AS build
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app/app.jar
COPY . /app/source
WORKDIR /app/source
EXPOSE 8001

FROM openjdk:18-jdk-alpine AS runtime
COPY --from=build /app/source/ /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

Comment: https://github.com/DimaPushka/taskone-release-v01

Comment: Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app/app.jar